# Camel with Spring JAX-WS

Tags: jax-ws, apache-camel, spring-ws

I have a Spring WS - JAX-WS application. It is exposing a Webservice.

Now I want to wrapper a Camel endpoint in front of it.

Such that, when the webservice is called, it should be routed by camel.  i.e.

Currently an able to hit the webservice using the URL **localhost/MyApp/appService?wsdl**

Which endpoint scheme should be used??

Answer (score 1):

Your JAX-WS application provides a [SOAP](http://www.w3schools.com/WebServices/default.asp) Web service.

So you can use [camel-soap](http://camel.apache.org/soap.html) or [camel-cxf](http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html), depending on your need.

**SOAP**

> SOAP is a Data Format which uses JAXB2 and JAX-WS annotations to
>   marshal and unmarshal SOAP payloads. It provides the basic features of
>   Apache CXF without need for the CXF Stack.

Here is a short exemple of use:

```
SoapJaxbDataFormat soap = new SoapJaxbDataFormat("com.example.customerservice", new ServiceInterfaceStrategy(CustomerService.class));
soap.setVersion("1.2");
from("direct:start")
  .marshal(soap)
  .to("jms:myQueue");
```

**CXF**

> The cxf: component provides integration with Apache CXF for connecting
>   to JAX-WS services hosted in CXF.

I will not provide an example for CXF because there is a lot more options. If you don't need them use SOAP, otherwise go see the [doc](http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html).

Comment: I tried the First method but am getting this error
"Result type of method getPersons is not annotated with WebParam. This is not yet supported"

Comment: It's maybe a new question. You should post your code and the stacktrace so that we can help you

Comment: Having the same issue, can you point me in the right direction, i.e. a link to the new question. ta.

Comment: Sorry this post is old, and I think, there never had a new question.